# Invite people to user chatter via Apex code

Tags: chatter

when I'm within a chatter group I can do two things:

1. Add a group member
2. Invite people

I know how to add a group member via Apex code, however I need to invite people to join this group through an email, but I cant find how to accomplish this with Apex.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Apex by [inserting a CollaborationInvitation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_collaborationinvitation.htm)

```
String emailAddress = 'bob@external.com';
CollaborationGroup chatterGroup = [SELECT Id 
      FROM CollaborationGroup 
      WHERE Name='All acme.com' 
      LIMIT 1];
CollaborationInvitation inv = New CollaborationInvitation();
inv.SharedEntityId = chatterGroup.id;
inv.InvitedUserEmail = emailAddress;

try {
   Insert inv;
} catch(DMLException e){
   System.debug('There was an error with the invite: '+e);
}
```

Comment: Is this example relevant for inviting customers?